# Delete blocks in awk if a specific word is encountered

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to use `awk` to print out only blocks that do not have the word `incomplete` on lines in between the `Start` and `End` lines.

I wrote this part based on a previous post, but the problem is that my lines do not start with `start` and `end`. I could swap them and put those records in the beginning of the lines, but if anybody knows an alternative, that would be much appreciated. Thank you!

[remove block of text between two lines based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670009/remove-block-of-text-between-two-lines-based-on-content)

```
awk '/Start/{rec=""; f=1} f{rec = rec $0 ORS} /End/{ if (f && (rec !~ "Incomplete")) printf "%s",rec; f=0}' file
```

```
awk '
   /Start/ {rec=""; f=1} # find the start of the record, reset the string to hold it and set a flag to indicate we've started processing a record
   f {rec = rec $0 ORS}    # append to the end of the string containing the current record
   /End/{      # find the end of the record
      if (f && (rec !~ "REGISTER")) # print the record if it doesn't contain "REGISTER"
         printf "%s",rec
      f=0                  # clear the "found record" indicator
   }
' file
```

Comment: What *does* your input look like?

Comment: Telling us 2 words that your blocks do not start and end with is not particularly useful. You can probably guess what WOULD be useful...

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it in `awk`

```
cat file
Hello
Start
some data
more
End
Data
Start
Yes
Here is more
This is incomplete
Not my day
End
```

```
awk '/Start/ {f=1} f {s=s?s"\n"$0:$0;if ($0~/incomplete/) f=s=0} /End/ && f {print s;f=s=0}' file
Start
some date
more
End
```

It will only print `Start` to `End` section if it does not contain `incomplete`

---

Some more readable:

```
awk '
    $0~start    {                       # If `Start` is found, do:
                f=1}                    # Set flag `f` to `1`
    f           {                       # If flag `f` is true do:
                s=s?s"\n"$0:$0          # Create block of data. (Take care of start correctly)
                if ($0~/incomplete/)    # If line does contain `incomplete` do:
                    f=s=0}              # Clear block of data `s` and clear flag `f`
    $0~end && f {                       # If `End` is found and flag `f` is true, do:
                print s                 # Print block of data `s`
                f=s=0}                  # Clear block of data `s` and clear flag `f`
    ' start="$start" end="$end"         # Read `start` and `stop` from variable
    file                                # Name of input file
```