# AWK - Filter matching

Tags: awk

I have a large text file that can be broken into multiple sections, each of which has the header `ABC` and footer `!!`.
A typical file would look like this

```
ABC
….
….
Status UP
….
!!
ABC
….
….
Status Down
….
!!
```

I need to retrieve only the sections that start with `ABC` and end with `!!` and do *not* include `Status Down`.

I tried the below command, which let me retrieve all sections with no exclusion:

```
awk '/^ABC/,/!!/' $input_file
```

How to apply the exclusion too?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670009/remove-block-of-text-between-two-lines-based-on-content

Answer (score 1):

This will print all the status up sections:

```
awk  '/Status UP/' RS='!!\n' file
```

#### How it works

awk reads in files one record at a time.  We define the record separator, `RS`, as `!!\n` so that each section is a separate record.  If the record contains `Status UP`, then print that record.

To be more explicit, we could have written the command as:

```
/Status UP/{print $0}
```

This would print any record that contained `Status UP`.  Since printing the record is the default action, it is sufficient to simplify the command to `/Status UP/`, leaving off the `{print $0}` part.

#### Alternative

Instead of selecting records that contain `Status UP`, we could exclude sections that contain `Status Down`:

```
awk  '!/Status Down/' RS='!!\n' file
```

`!` is the awk symbol for negation.  So, the condition `!/Status Down/` is true for any record that does not contain `Status Down`.

Comment: This is elegant.  What happens if there is data between a `!!` line and the next `ABC` line?  Granted the sample doesn't show that possibility, and it isn't mentioned, but … is there a way to fix your solution to handle that?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler To remove everything in a record up to the first occurrence of ABC, one possibility is `awk -F'\n' '/Status UP/{f=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){f=f?1:$i~/ABC/; if (f)print $i;}}' RS='!!\n' file`.  Alternatively, to eliminate everything up to the _last_ occurrence of ABC, one possibility is `awk  '/Status UP/{sub(/^.*ABC/,"ABC"); print}' RS='!!\n' file`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{d=0;s=0}/^ABC/,/!!/ {if($0~/Status Down/){d=1;i=s}if($0~/ABC/){s=i;d=0}if(d==0)a[i++]=$0} END {for (j=0; j<i;) print a[j++] }' file.txt
```

It stores each line in an array that gets printed at the end. s stores the most recent block start (ABC). d is 1 if the block should be excluded, 0 if not. If it finds "Status Down" then it resets i to the start of the block and sets d to 1. A the start of a new block d is set to 0.

Multiline with comments:

```
awk 'BEGIN{d=0;s=0} # intialise variables
    /^ABC/,/!!/     # match between record start and end
    {
        if($0~/Status Down/){d=1;i=s}   # set flag and reset pos
        if($0~/ABC/){s=i;d=0}   # clear flag and set start pos
        if(d==0)a[i++]=$0       # write out line if flag is clear
    }
    END {for (j=0; j<i;) print a[j++] }' file.txt
```

Comment: Why on earth is that all on one line?  For pity's sake, put the script on multiple lines so it can be read.  "One-liner" is a pejorative epithet, not a term of praise!

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can also do it as:

```
awk '/ABC/{rec=""; f=1} f{rec = rec $0 ORS}; /Status/{if(f && (rec ~ "Down")){rec=""; f=0;}}; /!!/{if(f) printf "%s",rec;f=0}' filename
```

For understanding, I have split it into lines.

```
awk '/ABC/{rec=""; f=1}
     f{rec = rec $0 ORS};
     /Status/{if(f && (rec ~ "Down")){rec=""; f=0;}};
     /!!/{if(f) printf "%s",rec;f=0}'
filename
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents for:

```
awk 'BEGIN{x=1}
     /^!!/   {flag=0;if(x){L=j}else{j=L};x=1}
     /Status UP/{x=0}
     flag    {a[++j]=$0;next}
     /^ABC/ {flag=1}
     END     {for (i=1;i<=j;i++){print a[i]}}' filename
```

it *rewinds* the index if the `Status UP` pattern is present between the tags.